# fetching and saving firestore data in redux

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-firestore

I am attempting to update my store with an asynchronous redux action. The initial database query collects the `contact` docs needed to make the second query for the nested `notes` due to shallow query limitations.
I am pushing the `notes` to `notesArray`, with a final push to contacts to include the `contacts data/id` and the `notesArray`.
I am receiving an error:

> non extensible object

This error does not persist when removing the `notes` query, and the `contacts` load fine without the `note` data...
Also, I can overcome the error if I copy the `contacts` array using something like `copyContacts = contacts`, but for whatever reason it's not available outside the scope of the function. How can I fix this?

```
export const fetchContactData = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {

            let contacts = [];

            await getDocs(collection(db, 'contacts')).then((docs) => {

                docs.forEach(async doc => {

                    const notesArray = [];

                    //this query is messing it up! This is causing the contacts array to be empty...
                    await getDocs(collection(db, 'contacts', doc.id, 'notes')).then((notes) => {
                        notes.forEach(note => {
                            notesArray.push({ ...note.data(), id: note.id })
                        })
                    })

                    contacts.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id, notes: notesArray})
                })

            });

            dispatch(contactActions.replaceContactData({
                contacts: contacts || []
            }));

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            dispatch(
                uiActions.showNotification({
                    status: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Error loading contacts.'
                })
            );
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's forEach loop was not designed for asynchronous code, a for...of loop was the solution.